# Pageable support for Neo4j version 4.0

Tags: spring-data-neo4j

With the new 4.0 release of Neo4J a number of deprecated features have been removed, most notably the old `{parameter}` reference. If you have a `Neo4jRepository` with a `Pageable` query and upgrade your Neo4j to version 4.0+ you will get the following exception:

```
The old parameter syntax `{param}` is no longer supported. Please use `$param` instead (line 3, column 15 (offset: 168))
"return o SKIP {sdnSkip} LIMIT {sdnLimit}"
```

I'm interested to know if the Spring Data Neo4J team is aware of this and working to fix the issue. And also if they plan to support both styles of parameter referencing, or only `$param` going forward.

The only possible workaround today is to avoid `Pageable`and specify SKIP and LIMIT explicitly in queries.

/Klaus

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to you mentioning this, we created https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAGRAPH-1300 and this will get fixed with the next (service) releases.

Most of the heavy lifting gets done by Neo4j Object Graph Mapper.
This includes creating queries.
There are some places in Spring Data Neo4j we have not yet updated that create queries by themself and pass those on to the OGM.

Comment: Thanks for noticing.I was tempted to do a pull request, but I didn't know if you wanted to be backwards compatible with Neo4j 2.0 or only use ```$param```and support 3.0+. If you want to be backwards compatible you need to detect the version of Neo4j, before deciding how to augment the query for pagination, which makes it a bit more complicated.

Comment: The supported versions of SDN and Neo4j-OGM are only 3.x and soon 4.x (x depending on the lib version you are using). There is no official support for Neo4j 2.x coming from these libraries.

Comment: @KlausGroenbaek How were you able to work around this issue? I am stuck in the same issue. Can you give me a code snippet ?

Comment: @meistermeier Will we get this fixed in the next release (2.2.6-Release) of spring-boot-starter-data-neo4j

Answer (score 1):

It will be part of next week‘s Spring Data Moore SR 6. Since the Spring Boot starter is part of the Spring Boot releases, you need to manually upgrade Spring Data until there is an updated starter.